# Мне будет очень жаль, если он умрет

Tags: синтаксис

Стараюсь определить вид придаточного предложения:

> Мне будет очень жаль, **если он умрет.**

Cкажите, пожалуйста, какой вопрос надо правильно задавать? *Чего мне будет жаль* или *При каком условии я буду испытывать сожале́ние* (если он умрет)? Изъяснительное или условное?

Спасибо!

Comment: При каком условии я буду испытывать сожале́ние? (если он умрет).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ЖАЛЬ**. I. в функц. безл. сказ. 1. кого (чего) и с инф. О чувстве жалости, сострадания. Ж. мне моего бесприютного друга.  Ж. огорчать тебя. 2. (с инф.). Досадно, грустно, печально.  Ж. расставаться. Ж., что уже похолодало.

Чувство жалости связано **с лицами, предметами, событиями**, поэтому требуется дополнительное пояснение, к чему конкретно оно относится. Соответственно, изъяснительное значение в этом случае всегда присутствует.

1) **Жаль (чего?), что он уехал/уезжает.**

Это настоящее или прошедшее время. **Придаточное изъяснительное** предложение обозначает событие, которое вызывает чувство жалости.

2) **Будет жаль (чего и в каком случае?), если он уедет. Мне будет очень жаль, если он умрет.**

Это будущее время и предполагаемое событие, союз ЕСЛИ выражает потенциальное условие. Изъяснительное значение (чувство жалости по отношению к данному событию) дополнено значением условия (если это событие совершится в будущем).

Таки образом, в данном случае совмещены **значения изъяснения и условия**. Можно сказать, что это придаточное **изъяснительное с дополнительным значением условия.**

Сравнить: Прогулку отменят, если будет дождь. Это  только условное придаточное.

Comment: Спасибо большое! =)